# Access DateTime field Update contents

Tags: vba, datetime, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a table in a Access 2010 database where 2 columns are datetime.

After I import an excel file I end up with

02:55:00

00:50:00
etc

Only issue is the data should look like

00:02:55

00:00:50
etc

I cant change the fields in the access files as another process relies on this structure later on.

The format in the excel also cannot be changed and the columns are Custom - [m]:ss

I was wondering is the a way to use VBA to check field and then update. maybe convert to text then manipulate and convert back and update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very simple method is to update:

```
Update YourTable
Set TimeField = TimeField / 60
```

Better would be not to import but link the Excel data. Then use the linked table as source in query where you convert data as needed.

Now, use this query for your further processing/import.

Comment: Thanks knew there would be a better method

Comment: Yes. String handling of date/time should be the last option.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys I have come up with this, which seems to work, not sure if best method or not.

```
Sub FixTime()

Dim rs As Recordset

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Table1")
rs.MoveFirst
Do While Not rs.EOF
   If Not IsNull(rs!test) Then
     a = CStr(rs!test)
     b = "00:" & Mid(a, 1, 5)
     c = CDate(b)
     rs.Edit
     rs!test = c
     rs.Update
   End If
   rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: This may work, but usually you should prefer SQL- over Recordset-Operations, because they are faster. Additionally the recordset edit/add has the disadvantage of locking records and you maybe violate the maxlocksperfile-limit if your recordset is huge. This can be avoided by using dbOpenSnapShot in Openrecordset (which makes the recordset non-updateable) and perform the update with a SQL-Updatequery for each record in the loop, but with @Gustav divison (as Time/Date are stored as numbers in db) not forth and back conversion.